# How to make a section without margin with the command "\exersize" like this:

Tags: macros, sectioning, framed

[image]

‎

```
\documentclass[12pt‎ , ‎a4paper]{report}‎
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}‎
\usepackage{titlesec}‎‎
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.2cm,right=6.2‎cm,marginparwidth=4.5‎cm‎,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}‎
\usepackage{titletoc}
‎\newcommand{\exersize}{‎‎\section*‎{exersize}‎‎‎}‎
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
‎\begin{document}‎‎‎‎

‎\chapter{Chapter one}‎

‎‎\section{Section 1}‎‎‎‎
\exersize
‎
‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please have a look on various possibilities, such as `amsthm` or `tcolorbox` etc.

Answer (score 2):

An example with a theorem like environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.2cm,right=6.2cm,marginparwidth=4.5cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newmdtheoremenv[%
  outerlinewidth=2,roundcorner=2pt,leftmargin=0,rightmargin=0,
  outerlinecolor=blue,innertopmargin=\topskip,splittopskip=\topskip,
]{exercise}{Exercise}%[section]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section 1}

\begin{exercise}[optional argument]
foo bar baz
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\blindtext
\end{exercise}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much. I whant no marginpar like style's marginpar chapter and box just around "Exersize"

Comment: that is easy: `\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{Exercise}`

Comment: I whant no Margin

Comment: @iman: Which margin do you mean? Between the box frame and "Exercise"? Reduce `\fboxseprule` then when using `\fcolorbox.`

Comment: Tanks. I whant no border the page and no fancy for section Exercise.

Comment: I whant a section Withot border and fancy

Comment: with the `report`class you do not get the output which you are showing in your question! There will be _no_ indentation for the section. You are using a different class or setting.